# Python requests 404

Tags: python, requests, http-status-code-404

При парсинге необходимо ссылки брать из txt файла, написал такой код, выводит 404

```
link1 = open("spisok_kategory.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
links = link1.readlines()
for link in links:
    URL_TEMPLATE = link
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
    print(r.status_code)
link1.close()
```

при выводе link выводит исправные ссылки, не пойму почему нет соединения
В txt ссылки без ""
Пробовал с юзерагентом, не помогло

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина

Comment: Попробуйте `URL_TEMPLATE = link.rstrip()`. Вроде бы при чтении из файла внутри строк остается перенос на следующую строку.

Comment: @insolor , спасибо, заработало